# Jaspersoft Studio 6.6.0 can't change the JRE

Tags: java, jaspersoft-studio

I'm having a problem using Jaspersoft Studio.

I generate many jasper reports through a Java application, but when I try to generate a report that has a subreport in it I get the: "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" error

Which I know means that the .jasper is being compiled using 1.8 and the java application is running on 1.7.

Now, I'm banging my head against a wall when I try to change the "compiler compliance level" on JasperSoft Studio (window > preferences > Compiler) from 1.8 to 1.7

The program itself tells me I need to activate the JRE before I can use it, but the interface button that would let me do that is unresponsive.

I've tried downloading the jre 1.7 from Oracle and putting it on the "jasper/TIB_js-studiocomm_6.6.0/features" folder, then changed the "JaspersoftStudio.ini" to reflect the new path, but I get a configuration error.

Is there any other way that I could change the jre used by JasperSoft Studio to compile ?

Comment: I've got the same problem - frustrating because when you click to add a JRE, it brings you to what seems to be the wrong preference pane.

Comment: What I  ended up doing was downloading a previous version of JasperSoft Studio (6.0.0) which used 1.7 by default, and just loaded the jrxml files and compiled from there.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing too, @LucaPB though I went for 5.6.1.  And even then, after install, it was still looking for Java 1.8.  So I needed to uninstall all other versions of Jasper Studio, then remove the .eclipse directory, then reinstall the older version of Jasper Studio and then update my project properties to use the older Java version.  It shouldn't be this hard to change Java versions!